# Indent and mark paragraphs

Tags: environments, paragraphs

I need an environment that indents one or more paragraphs and draws a gray line at the normal indentation level that matches the paragraph in height. This is what I came up with:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{colortbl}

\newenvironment{note}{
  \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}p{0.1cm}p{0.2cm}p{\dimexpr \textwidth - 1.1cm - 4\tabcolsep}}
    & &
}{
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
  Normal text

  \begin{note}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  \end{note}

  More normal text
\end{document}
```

This renders:

[image]

While the line itself looks fine, the vertical spacing is awful. I can of course insert some `\vspace` in the environment, but I think the whole approach with the `tabular` does not seem the best way to do this. Is there a better solution?

Comment: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basis of the environment you want already exists, if I've well understood: it's `leftbar` from the `framed` package. Here are two ways of patching it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed} %
 \usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{note}{
\leavevmode \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}p{0.1cm}p{0.2cm}p{\dimexpr \textwidth - 1.1cm - 4\tabcolsep}}
    & &
}{
  \end{tabular}
\vskip\topsep}


        \renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
        \def\FrameCommand{{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{\dimexpr\parindent-3pt-\fontdimen2\font\relax}}%
        \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}\parindent=0pt}%
        {\endMakeFramed}

        \newenvironment{myleftbar}{%
        \def\FrameCommand{{\hskip1em\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width 3pt} \hspace{3pt}}%
        \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}\parindent =0pt}%
        {\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}

  Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text.
  \begin{leftbar}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  \end{leftbar}
 Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text. Normal text.
  \begin{myleftbar}%
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat.
  \end{myleftbar}

  More normal text. More normal text. More normal text. More normal text. More normal text. More normal text. More normal text. More normal text.

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Avoid the `minimal` class, even if it used in the question.

Comment: Why? I never used it myself, so I don't know what problems it has.

Comment: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)